how to disable android default splashscreen or make icon fit
i have an issue with the splash screen , there is a default one which takes the logo of the app and put it in the center, what i prefer to do is to disable it and make my own , but i can't find a way , so i can settle with just making  my icon fit the entire space around it
here is a screenshot

i have tried changing the theme of  the app is seen in some videos but it seems that splash screen styed the same
any help please?, thanks

It should probably be from your icon. When adding it in Android studio, did you resize it appropriately?. Are you using svg?

yes i import it as svg , and tried different sizes

Follow the official doc: Splash Screen
Make sure your icon content takes full the entire space of your icon size.
Then set "windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" to you icon.
And set "windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor" to transparent.
